# Is there any methodology or technology to post process the Mobile/Tablet GPS data

Tags: gps, android, latitude-longitude

We have developed an application which is running on android OS for collecting the Lat/Long value of any feature and it runs in any type of android Tablet/Mobile but the problem is that the accuracy is very poor (because the accuracy is depends upon the GPS receiver of that device).

Is there any methodology  or technology to post process the GPS data?

Comment: What range of accuracy are you getting? What accuracy do you need? Under what conditions is the data being recorded?

Comment: Commonly we use any type of android tab/mobile, so the accuracy of that device would be 10 to 20met.and as per our requirement the accuracy should be in between 3 met.Our captured data stored in mobile data format(.sqlite) and finally it would be converted into .shp format.

Comment: Are you measuring a track or a point? What's the time of measurment? Is the feature measured already present in the db and you just want to know which one it is? Are you looking to implement in on the mobile site or on the server?

Comment: the only technology I know of is to use  a true gps that has post-processing capability and blue tooth it. That being said depending on your software prowess you could stat with an open source library and build your own. The data format is pretty simple. Timestamp to  the 100/10000 of a second I think, and then download time files from base, differential math from there and an output.

Comment: In our application, user has to design a form for any type of asset survey in our backend process, and then go to field with the HHU and capture the asset information with the latitude/longitude value on the help of HHU's inbuilt GPS. we are unable to post process that value in any type of GIS software.So please confirm, is this possible to post process the HHU's lat/long value or not and if yes, then what is the procedure to do that activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really expect much from amateur gps recievers but a kalman filter should help. You should check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134579/smooth-gps-data).

You might also want to checkout DGPS.